# Rails4: CKEditor gsub error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, gsub

I have a project in rails 4 that uses ckeditor with cloudinary. The uplaod to Cloudinary works fine, but after the upload, when the editor should lad the image, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass:
```

[image]

My CKEditor Picture Uploader is:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick



  [:extract_content_type, :set_size, :read_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      {}
    end
    alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
  end

  process :read_dimensions

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [118, 100]
  end

  version :content do
    process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end
end
```

When I go to upload and click on "find image on server" the image is there and I can load the image on editor, but not when I upload image to server

Someone got this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because `gsub` could not find url for Uploaded image in ckeditor. You have to create [ckeditor asset_response.rb](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb) file in your lib/ckeditor folder of your App and put this line of code

```
def asset_url(relative_url_root)
  @ckeditor_assets = Ckeditor::Picture.last.url_content
  puts @ckeditor_assets.inspect
  #return nil if asset.url_content.nil?
  url =  @ckeditor_assets #Ckeditor::Utils.escape_single_quotes(asset.url_content)

  if URI(url).relative?
    "#{relative_url_root}#{url}"
  else
    url
  end
end
```

put the whole code and replace asset_url method with this.
This is just a hack to include `Ckeditor::Picture` model.

Put this code for cloudinary in CkeditorPictureUploader file

```
include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave 
   process :tags => ["photo_album_sample"]
   process :convert => "jpg"
   version :thumbnail do
     eager
     resize_to_fit(200, 200)
     cloudinary_transformation :quality => 80          
   end
```

Comment: Thanks! There is no lib/ckeditor folder. I should create one?

Comment: I just tried to create the file: libs/ckeditor/asset_response.rb and put the code there. But I still git the same error. I'm not found the CKEDITOR folder of gem in my project, so I think I sould create this file on LIB folder of my project?

Comment: Yes you have to create folder in `lib` ckeditor/asset_response.rb file and check ckeditor folder is present in model or not.

Comment: Hi, Thnaks! I did that. I create the file /lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb and check the folder /model/ckeditor. But I'm still getting the error: `NoMethodError at /pictures undefined method gsub for nil:NilClass`. The code for `CkeditorPictureUploader` is also there, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you try to break code at every function of `asset_response.rb` and check from console if all values are successfully saved in database or not. start from `initialize(asset, request)`

Answer (score 0):

From @t-s 's answer, I found that in [Ckeditor::AssetResponse#asset_url](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb#L89) 
method, the `asset` object is not reloaded, so `asset.content_url` will always be nil thus caused the error. I fixed it like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly for `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile` class if you have it.